# using qt activex property value in js always return empty

Tags: qt, activex

I am buiding a qt axserver dll with a Qt property like :

```
class testDll : public QObject , public QAxBindable
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_CLASSINFO("ClassID", "{}")
    Q_CLASSINFO("InterfaceID", "{}")
    Q_CLASSINFO("EventsID", "{}")

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name MEMBER m_name READ getName WRITE setName)

public:
    testDll(QObject *parent = 0);
    QString getName() const;

public slots:
    void setName(QString v);

signals:
    void nameChanged(QString v);

private:
    QString m_name;
};
```

when I use this dll in a axcontainer I built for test, I can get the property value like this `QString res = container->dynamicCall("name").toString();`, but when I use this property in IE like this `var name = testDll.name; console.log(name);`, it always return empty.

I tried  `Q_PROPERTY(int number MEMBER m_number READ getNumber WRITE setNumber)`, it is ok to get the property value in IE using following two ways:

```
        var dll = document.getElementById("testDll");
        var num1 = dll.number;
        console.log(num1);
        var num2 = testDll.number;
        console.log(num2);
```

I am new to activex and could not find good tutorial about qt activex developing. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this. It's actually kind stupid: `name` cannnot be used as Q_PROPERTY name. After I change the property name, it works.